# Automatically choosing bean version to inject in CDI

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

I have the following packages and classes structure in my Java Enterprise appication:

```
com
    common
        VersionInfo
    V1
        MainService
        RequestDataProvider
    V2
        MainService
        RequestDataProvider
```

The classes are related with the following dependency diagram:

[image]

Is there a way to automatically inject `RequestDataProvider` to `VersionInfo` from the same package in which is `MainService`?

Comment: Why do you want to keep your `v1` at first?

Comment: Because I need classes from both v1 and v2 packages.

Comment: There is no way to do that apart (maybe) from some heavy magic with CDI extensions. You can always use qualifiers instead - have a qualifier for each version, perhaps?

Comment: usually java programmers do not version controlling like that . create new version of class or method and used @Depricated on old codes .